# Jenkins with SVN branches in non-standard locations?

Tags: svn, jenkins, branch, jenkins-plugins

I know that it's possible to [track all SVN branches with Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146202/configure-jenkins-to-work-with-svn-branches) using the "List Subversion Tags" build parameterisation options. But as far as I can see, this method relies on a standard `branches/<branch>` structure. Our organisation uses a `branches/Users/<user>/<branch>` structure, so the SVN plug-in considers there to only be one branch (`Users`). Is there any way to get the plug-in's branch auto-detection to recognise this alternative branch structure?

Comment: Are you looking to have builds using these branches be automated? or you just need a way to expose them as an option for manual builds

Comment: If you don't need to automate a build I think you should be able to just get away with specifying the path down into the Users folder in your svn url: `url to repo/branches/Users/` Then just leave Tags filter, default value and max tags to display all blank (side note in a recent update to the plugin leaving default blank was changed to trigger a build with the most recent tag so I'm not sure how that would affect things here).  In terms of automation you'd have to have the starting job pass in the right <user> as the parameter which would require a bit more work

Comment: @Tuffwer: I want to be able to select branches as a build parameterisation, ideally in a way such that users can run the tests just on their own branches..