# Configure a Jenkins job to select an application and trunk/tags/branches from SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, hudson

We want to use a single Jenkins job to build an application.

The solution from [How to configure a single Jenkins job to make the release process from trunk or branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7751735/2886891) does *not* work since **our SVN structure is different** (from historical reasons and we cannot change it):

```
http://my-svn-repo/projects/
├───branches
│   ├───app1
│   │   ├───BRANCH_A
│   │   ├───BRANCH_B
│   │   └───BRANCH_C
│   ├───app2
│   │   ├───BRANCH_D
│   │   ├───BRANCH_E
│   │   └───BRANCH_F
│   └───app3
│       ├───BRANCH_G
│       ├───BRANCH_H
│       └───BRANCH_I
├───tags
│   ├───app1
│   │   ├───BRANCH_D
│   │   ├───BRANCH_E
│   │   └───BRANCH_F
│   ├───app2
│   │   ├───TAG_D
│   │   ├───TAG_E
│   │   └───TAG_F
│   └───app3
│       ├───TAG_G
│       ├───TAG_H
│       └───TAG_I
└───trunk
    ├───app1
    ├───app2
    └───app3
```

The described solution [How to configure a single Jenkins job to make the release process from trunk or branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7751735/2886891) shows for selection this:

- trunk
- branches/app1
- branches/app2
- branches/app3
- tags/app1
- tags/app2
- tags/app3

What we would like to have is the following:

Selection 1:

- app1
- app2
- app3

Selection 2 (automatically based on the selection 1, e.g. for app2):

- trunk
- BRANCH_D
- BRANCH_E
- BRANCH_F
- TAG_D
- TAG_E
- TAG_F

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Active Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) and Groovy script.

1. Create parameter `APP` to select the application. The Groovy script is expected to return the list of selections, so just return the hard-coded list (or read it from a file or from anywhere you wish):

[image]

2. Create parameter `VERSION` to select the version.

   - Now use *Active Choice **Reactive** Parameter*, so you are able to react to the changes of the parameter APP.
   - The Groovy Script gradually builds the list of choices to be selectable. First trunk, then tags, then branches.
   - The data are obtained using the command-line [svn list](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) in the form of

   `svn list http://my-svn-repo/projects/tags/appX --username some_name --password some_password`

   - *Referenced parameters* must be set to `APP`. Whenever the value of `APP` is updated, the Groovy script will re-evaluate the choice list using the updated values of referenced parameters.

[image]

Here is the script for copy & paste:

```groovy
def svnBaseUrl = 'http://my-svn-repo/projects/'
def versions = ['trunk/' + APP]

def svnTagsUrl = svnBaseUrl + 'tags/' + APP
def command = ['svn', 'list', svnTagsUrl,'--username', 'some_name', '--password', 'some_password']
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitForOrKill(10000)
if ( proc.exitValue() == 0 ) {
  proc.text.eachLine { versions.add('tags/' + APP + '/' + it) }
}

def svnBranchesUrl = svnBaseUrl + 'branches/' + APP
command = ['svn', 'list', svnTagsUrl,'--username', 'some_name', '--password', 'some_password']
proc = command.execute()
proc.waitForOrKill(10000)
if ( proc.exitValue() == 0 ) {
  proc.text.eachLine { versions.add('branches/' + APP + '/' + it) }
}

return versions
```

3. In the *Build Triggers* section, set another variable (for better readability): `BASE_SVN_URL=http://my-svn-repo/projects`

[image]

4. Now you have all the variables ready and you may print them to the Jenkins job console:

[image]

The script for copy & paste:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "================================================"
echo "Parameters for the build:"
echo "Application:  $APP"
echo "Base SVN URL: ${BASE_SVN_URL}"
echo "Version:      ${VERSION}"
echo "SVN URL:      ${BASE_SVN_URL}/${VERSION}"
echo "================================================"
```

During testing, you may add a line at the end of the script to immediately terminate your job and just see the values:

```bash
exit 1
```

5. Finally, call another Jenkins job `Build-application-core-job`, which will perform the actual build. Pass the job all the necessary parameters:

[image]

6. When you run your job, you will get a screen with two parameters, where the second will one always contain the valid values depending on the value of the first one:

[image]

7. Last but not least: following standards is good :) Had you followed standards, you could have used the *List Subversions tags (and more)* plugin almost out of the box as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32622725/2886891

Answer (score 0):

You can use one or booth of the plugins below.

1 - [Dynamic Extended Choice Paramenter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin)
This seems to make exactly what you want but I never use this one.

2 - [Dynamic Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in) In this you can configure a script to read all app's, branch or trunks and transform this on choices options for your job or just add a list of static options.