# Groovy not running as expected in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Groovy script to list branches in my svn is not working properly in Jenkins. It's working fine when it is run standalone.

1. I tried the code at this really nice answer in stackoverflow: [Configure a Jenkins job to select an application and trunk/tags/branches from SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549683/configure-a-jenkins-job-to-select-an-application-and-trunk-tags-branches-from-sv/41632406#41632406)
2. Googling for about 3 days without any solution.
3. FYI, I tried it in the Active choices plugin and the script console of Jenkins.
4. Tried minor variations of the same code without any success.

Here is the groovy script used:

```
try {
    println 'Entering script file....'
    def versions = [];
    def svnCommand = "svn list <url> --username '<usname>' --password 'pwd'"
    def proc = svnCommand.execute() 
    println 'proc alive ==='+proc.isAlive()
    proc.waitFor()
    println 'proc ==='+proc
    println 'status = ' + proc.exitValue()
    if ( proc.exitValue() == 0 ) {
      proc.text.eachLine { 
        versions.add('branches/' + '/' + it) 
        println 'branch = ' + it
      }
    }
    println 'branches in file = ' + versions
    return versions
} catch (Throwable e) {
    println 'exception: ' + e.toString()
}
```

Actual result of the above code in Jenkins log:

```
Entering script file...
proc alive ===true
proc ===java.lang.ProcessImpl@b8a821
status = 1
branches in file = []
```

Expected result:

```
...
status = 0
branches in file = <list of branches>
```

Comment: The problem might not be the groovy script itself. What is the output of the svn command in stdout and stderr? Is svn in the Jenkins environment `PATH`?

Comment: Yes. The problem is definitely not in the script itself. As mentioned, it is working fine if I run it separately. It's not working only in Jenkins.

Comment: the SVN list command in stdout displays the branches correctly. Not sure if SVN is in Jenkins environment PATH. Can you please let me know how to verify? But SVN plugin is working fine.

Comment: SVN is in the global path environmental variable: $PATH:C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin

Comment: Can you add `proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)` after `def proc = svnCommand.execute() ` to see what the process logs?

Comment: Fantastic! I got this error: err:svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL '<url>'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted.                                                   So, Not sure why this happens though? The svn plugin works fine but this is not.